# IoT/WinJS/VS - Failed to create the web diagnostics object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, winjs, iot

I have successfully installed Windows 10 Insider Preview and Visual Studio 2015 RC on my PC, and Windows IOT Core on my Pi.

I have created a new JavaScript Windows Universal App solution in Visual Studio, and tried to deploy as-is, i.e. the project as supplied in the template. When trying to run the program on the remote machine, in either debug or release modes, the project deploys and runs successfully, however Visual Studio advises with a modal dialog box during the deployment process:

"Failed to create the web diagnostics object. The JavaScript Console and DOM Explorer may not work. Repairing the remote debugger installation may help".

Firstly, can I expect these tools to work on the Pi for a JavaScript Windows Universal App?

Secondly, I don't know how to repair or even access the remote debugger software. It seems to run automatically (msvsmon.exe, twice). Is here something to configure properly to get it to run?

Regards,

Paul

Comment: same issue VS 2015 Community RTM + PI Version 10.0.10240.16384

Comment: Same here, and C# does not work either due to a different VS bug. :(

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that you don't have admin access to remote machine, which is natural assuming that you didn't have activated developer mode in BOTH machines.

otherwise, I could say that this could be a bug(but only if you can see the DOM in explorer) you can't disable DOM explorer in V.S either so if this didn't fix the issue and it's annoying, then you will have to wait for update 1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found was to install Windows 10 on my Dev computer. It appears like this does indeed not work with Windows 8.